# Interacting with ace editor using selenium programmatically

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm trying to do some web scraping with `selenium-webdriver`.
The particular page uses the ace editor for syntax highlighting. The problem is that I can enter text using

```
driver.get "http://codetable.org"
elem = driver.find_element(:css, "#editor textarea")
elem.send_keys "Hello"
```

but I can't clear the text that is once entered. `elem.clear` has no impact on the page.

Is there some way I can delete the text that is on the screen programmatically? I suspect this is because of the extra css that ace adds.
I'm using `ruby 1.9.3`.

I've also tried this

```
irb(main):035:0> driver.find_element(:css, ".ace_content").clear
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
    from [remote server]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when a value is inputted into the textarea, it is applied to another span. The textarea always has a blank value, which explains why `clear` does not work appear to do anything.

If you want to clear the text, I think you might have to use keyboard shortcuts - ctrl+a and then delete. Try:

```
elem.send_keys [:control, 'a'], :delete
```